# jQuery - Maintain Order of .each() while using .getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, each, getjson

I have a working function that checks for any input with a specific class name, then runs a getJSON call for each input's value:

```
function getTopFeeds() {
  if (jQuery('input.class-name').length > 0) {
    jQuery.each(jQuery('input.class-name'),function(){
      var feedName = jQuery(this).val();
      jQuery.getJSON("https://api.url/"+feedName).success(function(data) {
        if (!(data)) {
           return;
        }
        var result = data.results[0];
        if (result) {
            // Here I create HTML list items to display API data
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

It works, but because it's asynchronous it's not returning in the order the inputs on the page. How can I modify my existing function so that the data is displayed in the same order of the inputs?

Comment: Each invocation of `.each()` gives you an index. One possibility would be to create an Array of the same length as the number of requests you're making, and every time a response comes back, put the response in the Array at the index of that iteration.

Comment: ...you can then either process them all when complete, or maintain a separate counter that starts at `0`, and every time a new item gets added to the array, try iterating from the current position of the counter until it hits an `undefined` value in the array. This will let you provide ordered updates to the page without having to wait for them all to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to wait until they've all come back, you can keep the results in an array and remember how many results you've seen; when you've seen as many results as requests, you're done. See comments:

```
function getTopFeeds() {
    if (jQuery('input.class-name').length > 0) {
        // Get the inputs
        var inputs = jQuery('input.class-name');
        // Storage for the results
        var results = [];
        // Counter for # of responses we've seen
        var counter = 0;
        // Get them
        inputs.each(function(index) {
            var feedName = this.value;
            jQuery.getJSON("https://api.url/" + feedName)
                .done(function(data) {
                    // Got a response, save it or null if falsy (would that really happen?)
                    results[index] = data ? data.results[0] : null;
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    // Error response, use null as a flag
                    results[index] = null;
                })
                .always(function() {
                    // Called after `done` and `fail` -- see if we're done
                    if (++counter === inputs.length) {
                        // Yes, we're done -- use the results in `results`
                        // Note that there will be `null`s for any that
                        // didn't have data
                    }
                });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Appreciate the informative comments. Was able to get this integrated perfectly and output the order of the inputs by including a for loop in the .always() function to output the HTML elements for each feed.